# Ooyala Player in a user control

Tags: .net, scriptmanager

I have two controls. Control1 has two labels and Control2 has two Imagebuttons and a placeholder to contain the Ooyala Player.

Default aspx has above two controls each in an update panel and a menu control in another update panel (UP1 has C1, and UP2 has C2 and UP3 has Menu control).

Currently I am able to navigate from one control to another using Menu control.

In Control2, `CreateChildControls()`:

```
//Registersfor each partial postback, no display of player
            bool reg = HelperClass.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page), "trailer");
            string script = "<script type='text/javascript' src=\"http://player.ooyala.com/player.js?callback=receiveOoyalaEvent&playerId=player&width=480&height=360&embedCode=llMDQ6rMWxVWbvdxs2yduVEtSrNCJUk1&version=2\"></"+"script>";

            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "trailer", script, true);
            reg = HelperClass.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page), "trailer");
```

In debug mode, the reg is true so the script is registered. Why isn't the player seen on Control2?

Also this line to `CreateChildControls()`:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude(this, this.GetType(), "trailer", "http://player.ooyala.com/player.js?callback = receiveOoyalaEvent&playerId=player&width=480&height=360&embedCode=llMDQ6rMWxVWbvdxs2yduVEtSrNCJUk1&version=2");
```

Plays the player on Control2 but then menu navigation seems to be not working.

Can anyone explain this?